# How to get Bonded Devices in Android 4.3 API 18?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am developing an application where I have to connect to Bluetooth device on Android 4.3.

I can get the device-A that I have paireduse by using getBondedDevices().

But this device-A is connect via bluetooth in android->config->bluetooth, not

Does the Android 4.3 BLE 4.0 also use the getBondedDevices() to get the device that I have paired ??

or it has other method to get the pair Devices in BT 4.0 and API 18 ??

Comment: have you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get the bonded devices :

```
BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

if (mBluetoothManager != null) {
    BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    if (mBtAdapter != null) {
        final Set <BluetoothDevice> bonded = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    }
}
```